# Replace substring with <tag>substring</tag> in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, escaping, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to modify an existing html file so that specific keywords are printed as strong (no matter where they appear).

My attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
txt = """<html><head><style></style></head><body><h2>"This is my keyword</h2><table><tr><td>This could be another instance of the keyword.</td></tr></table></body></html>"""

buzz_words = ["keyword", "apples"]

htmlSoup = soup(txt, features="html.parser")
for word in buzz_words:
    target = htmlSoup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"" + re.escape(word)))
    for v in target:
        v.replace_with(v.replace(word, "".join(["<strong>", word, "</strong>"])))
print(str(htmlSoup))
```

Result:

```
This is my &lt ;strong&gt ;keyword&lt ;/strong&gt ;(spaces added by me)
```

Desired result:

```
This is my <strong>keyword</strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import html

txt = """<html><head><style></style></head><body><h2>"This is my keyword</h2><table><tr><td>This could be another instance of the keyword.</td></tr></table></body></html>"""

buzz_words = ["keyword", "apples"]

htmlSoup = soup(txt, features="html.parser")
for word in buzz_words:
    target = htmlSoup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"" + re.escape(word)))
    for v in target:
        v.replace_with(v.replace(word, "".join(["<strong>", word, "</strong>"])))
print(html.unescape(str(htmlSoup.prettify())))
```

Comment: This works and is only a slight adjustment to my code. Thank you very much for the quick help!